# C: Segmentation fault in doubly linked list, in append and delete function

Tags: c

I'm having problems with creating doubly linked list in C, as it's returning segmentation fault in append and delete. Seems like I'm pointing one of the pointers to a wrong place, but I'm having a hard time finding it.

My functions in question are as follows:

**Append:**

```
int list_append(list_t *list, int val) {
    if(!list) { return 1; }

//    create a new node, then assign the value
    struct node_t *new = (node_t *) malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    new->val = val;
    new->prev = NULL;
    new->next = NULL;

//    place the new node (since it is tail, make next null)
    new->next = NULL;

//    if there's no head(null), make the new node the head (and tail)
    if (list->head == NULL)
    {
        list->head = new;
    }

//    if the next value is not null, traverse until it is (=tail)
    struct node_t *node = list->head;

    while (node)
    {
        node = list->tail;
    }
//    place the new node at the next of tail
    list->tail->next = new;

//    set the old tail as the previous of new node
    new->prev = list->tail;

    list->tail->next = NULL;

    CHECK_LIST(list);

    return 0;
}
```

**Delete**:

```
int list_delete(list_t *list, int val) {
    if(!list) { return 1; }

    CHECK_LIST(list);

//    make a temporary node to help find the value
    struct node_t *temp = list->head;


//    start traversing the list

    while (temp)
    {

//      if match is found
        if (temp->val == val)
        {
//          if the match is actually the head, make the next node the new head,
//          then make old head null
            if (temp == list->head)
            {
                list->head = list->head->next;
                list->head->prev = NULL;
            }
//          if the match is at the tail, make the previous node the new tail,
//          then make the old tail null
            if (temp == list->tail)
            {
                list->tail = list->tail->prev;
                temp->prev->next = NULL;
            } else
            {
//              set new next of temp as the old next of temp, and vice versa
//              then, free temp from memory
                temp->next = temp->prev->next;
                temp->prev = temp->next->prev;

                temp = NULL;
                free(temp);
            }
        }

//      keep moving
        temp = temp->next;
    }

    CHECK_LIST(list);

    return 0;
}
```

Thank you for the help in advance.

Comment: Have you run gdb or valgrind on this?

Comment: I did, and on valgrind, it says:
`Invalid write of size 8
==18842==    at 0x400F97: list_append (list.c:167)
==18842==    by 0x400BAB: main (test-list.c:105)
==18842==  Address 0x8 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd`

Comment: what is the purpose of `while (node)
    {
        node = list->tail;
    }` if you are not using `node` anywhere afterwards in `append()` function

Comment: You don't need valgrind for this... :) Don't reinvent the wheel - take a look at [this](https://gist.github.com/mycodeschool/7429492) (top google hit for *"doubly linked list in c"*).

Comment: Please provide definitions for `list_t` and `node_t`

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in the below code block of `append()` function

```
while (node) {
    node = list->tail; /*what is tail here ?? */
}
/* after this loop you are not using node anywhere, what's the use 
    of iterating through loop */
//    place the new node at the next of tail
list->tail->next = new;
//    set the old tail as the previous of new node
new->prev = list->tail;
list->tail->next = NULL;
```

replace with

```
struct node_t *node = list->head;

while (node->next) {/* when loop fails node holds  last node address */
     node = list->next;
}
node->next = new; /* replace node->next as new node */
new->prev = node->next; /* new node previous make it as old node next */
new->next = NULL;/* last node next make it as 0*/
```

Better run first `gdb` and do `bt`

Comment: Isn't `new` a keyword in `C++`? it should not be used as variable name?

Comment: It's `C`, not `C++`.

Comment: No @GRC code is in `C` not in `C++` and in `C` `new` is not a keyword.

Comment: Well, my compiler was giving me error for `new` keyword, although it is `C` code.